# Android checkbox and text box on top of the other

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have the following FrameLayout, this layout is used to my RecyclerView as the rows. In etch row I have text box and checkbox. The problem is the checkbox and the text box are connected to each other and the checkbox on the top of the text and it's hide the text box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:focusable="false"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/undo_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_undo"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    />

<!-- quick and dirty divider -->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
    android:layout_width="323dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:allowUndo="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I would be happy if someone can help me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you share screen shot?

Comment: Check box has an inbuilt android:text element. can't you use it?

Comment: @Nabil In this time I can't use it.

Comment: @JaiminPrajapti I add a screen shot.

Comment: Can you show the design which you want to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/greenbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/undo_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/d"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/dummycheckbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/d"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dummytittletxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/undo_button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dummycheckbox"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dummycheckbox"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="textview" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:focusable="false"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/undo_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button_undo"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    style=""
    />

<!-- quick and dirty divider -->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
    android:layout_width="323dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:allowUndo="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="textview" />


</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The text is on the top of the checkbox, I need to make the text to be parallel to the checkbox. any other option ?

Comment: @asaproG try the updated code and change android:orientation="vertical" if required

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:focusable="false">

<!-- quick and dirty divider -->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:checked="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:allowUndo="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Aaadfdsaf"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/undo_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/button_undo"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    tools:text="Button" />
```

Change the gravity and position where you want, I don't have design so can't make how you need it